# Web API 2 Service With Windows Authentication Not Working in Chrome and Firefox with HTTPS Binding

Tags: https, iis-7, windows-authentication, kerberos, asp.net-web-api2

I am hosting a Web API 2 service (.NET 4.5.1) on a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS7 on a company intranet (server and clients are all in the same domain).  My web service uses ONLY Windows Authentication (Negotiate:Kerberos, Negotiate and NTLM providers are enabled in that order) and I have two site bindings (http:80 and https:443).  The problem is this: I am able to access the service in IE, Chrome and Firefox using the http:80 binding; however, I am only able to access the service in IE when using the https:443 binding.  When I try to access the service with the https:443 binding in Chrome and Firefox it keeps prompting for a username and password over and over again (I'm entering the correct credentials with and without the adding the domain to the username).  Here's a summary of the behavior:

**http:80 Binding:**

1. Internet Explorer **works** (no prompt for username and password).
2. Chrome **works** (after entering a username and password when prompted).
3. Firefox **works** (no prompt for username and password -- I enabled integrated Windows authentication by following the instructions [here](http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/)).

**https:443 Binding:**

1. Internet Explorer **works** (after entering a username and password when prompted).
2. Chrome **does not work** (it keeps prompting for a username and password over and over again).
3. Firefox **does not work** (it keeps prompting for a username and password over and over again).

Does anyone know why I can't use the https:443 binding in Chrome and Firefox?